# My code keeps updating my already existing values in the dictionary despite being new values, how can the code be fixed?

Tags: python

When I add a new pair of values for the dictionary in the form of variables (patientname : pinnumber), they replace the ones I've added before

```
menuoption = str(input("Option: "))
x = menuoption
while x != "EX":
if menuoption == "PR":
    print("Patient Registration [PR]")
    patientdict = {"VRogue Wan": 1234}


    patientname = str(input("Name: "))
    pinnumber = input("Pin Number: ")
    patientdict[patientname] = pinnumber

    menuoption = str(input("Option: "))
    x = menuoption

if menuoption == "PI":
    print("Patient Information [PI]")

    print(patientdict)

    menuoption = str(input("Option: "))
    x = menuoption
```

Comment: you initialize the dictionary inside the while loop in the if, may I suggest initializing `patientdict = {"VRogue Wan": 1234}` outside the while loop

Comment: Are you aware that dictionaries can't hold duplicate keys? Probably you tried entering same `patientname`.

Comment: Put `patentdict` outside of the loop. It's being redefined on every iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the dictionary outside the loop. You can create an empty dict, and let the user add values inside the loop.
Also no need to ask for `input("Option: ")` in each `if` block, place it at the beginning of the loop.

```
patientdict = {} #empty dict

while True:
    menuoption = input("Option: ")

    if menuoption == "PR":
        print("Patient Registration [PR]")
        patientname = input("Name: ")
        pinnumber = input("Pin Number: ")
        patientdict[patientname] = pinnumber

    if menuoption == "PI":
        print("Patient Information [PI]")
        print(patientdict)

    if menuoption == 'EX':
        break #exit the loop
```

In python3, `input` returns always a string, no need to call `str` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing of dict should be out of loop.

```
menuoption = str(input("Option: "))
x = menuoption
patientdict = {"VRogue Wan": 1234} # It should be out of loop
while x != "EX":
    if menuoption == "PR":
    print("Patient Registration [PR]")

    ... Other code ....
```